# Create a blob store in S3 for Nexus Sonatype

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, nexus, sonatype

I'm not able to configure the AWS-S3 blob store for Nexus sontaype. The nexus server is hosted on AWS-EC2 and I want to store all the binaries into the S3.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked this https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/high-availability/configuring-blob-stores

Comment: Can you add some detail on the problem you're having?  I don't feel this is an answerable question as written.